# Get S3 presigned url and preview it on the web using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the version 3 SDK of AWS s3 for php. I'm trying to get a pre-signed url with an expiration of 20 minutes. I believe I do get the presigned url but then when I try to copy and paste the url in the web browser, I couldn't view it. Do I miss something?

Here is my code:

```
$cmd = $this->s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
            'Key'    => 'Hydrangeas.jpg'
        ]);

        $request = $this->s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
        return $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

and in return I get this URL.

```
https://hydrangeas.jpg?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=*SOME CREDENTIALS*&X-Amz-Date=20191014T025356Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=1200&X-Amz-Signature=*SOME SIGNATURE KEY*
```

Comment: Your URL does not seem to include the name of the bucket. It should be something like: `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Hydrangeas.jpg?...`

Comment: Oh, so do I need to include the bucket name as well? Is it can be get from the SDK as well? Sorry I'm very new to this hehe

Comment: Are you sure `$this->bucket` is valid?

Comment: @AnonCoward yeap. This was intitated in the component file as a global variable